# Im textbox From 1 to 1000 write testcase to allow only multiple of 5 Using Equivalent partition and boundaries value analysis?

Tags: testing, analysis, partition, boundary, equivalence

Write test case for selecting only multiple of 5 from 1 to 1000 using equivalence partition and boundary analysis technique

Answer (score 0):

**Boundary Value analysis**

Based on your question the valid input space is 1 to 1,000. [Boundary Value Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis) is where you test the edges of the valid space. Therefore the best four test cases are:

- 0 - Invalid
- 1 - Valid
- 1000 - Valid
- 1001 - Invalid

In the invalid test cases you are checking that the correct (user understandable) error message is provided.

**Equivalence partition**

With [equivalence partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning) you split the input space into different partitions and have one test case per partition. Without any details on the implementation you only have three partitions:

- less than 1
- 1 to 1000
- more than 1000

From here you can pick an input for each of these partitions.

Comment: I want only multiple of 5 to be accepted in textbox